# (gtag) for AMP No triggers were found in the config. No analytics data will be sent

Tags: amp-html, amp-analytics

Try to setup google gtag to amp page. But always receive an error:

> [AmpAnalytics gtag] No triggers were found in the config. No analytics
>   data will be sent.

i get example code from https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/amp
setup my **GA_TRACKING_ID**

```
<amp-analytics type="gtag" data-credentials="include" id="gtag">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "vars": {
        "gtag_id": "<GA_TRACKING_ID>",
        "config": {
          "<GA_TRACKING_ID>": {}
        }
      },
      "triggers": {
        "button": {
          "selector": "#the-button",
          "on": "click",
          "vars": {
            "event_name": "login",
            "method": "Google"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

As u can see triggers is here, but this error always appear.

Thank you in advance for any and all assistance!

Comment: GA_TRACKING_ID is the "UA-XXXX" NOT "G-XXXXX" , I have tried so much and can't send event to the "WEB+MOBILE" property.

Comment: @BuffK Did you ever figure out how to send to the WEB+APP property using AMP analytics?

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

AMP integration with Google Analytics 4 (GA4) is still under development.

Follow the discussion [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/24621).
[Link to the parent issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/30903)